# Hadoop, how to normalize multiple columns data?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, normalization

I have a file .txt like this

1036177 19459.7356 17380.3761 18084.1440

1045709 19674.2457 17694.8674 18700.0120

1140443 19772.0645 17760.0904 19456.7521

where the first column represent the Key and the others are the values.
I would like to normalize (min-max) each column and after that sum up the columns.

Someone can give me some advice on how do that in MapReduce?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From an algorithmic perspective you'll need to:

- Mapper

  - Parse / tokenize each input line by it's delimiter (space?)
  - Use a Text object to encapsulate the key field
  - Either create a custom value class to encapsulate the other fields or use an `ArrayWritable` wrapper
  - Output this Key / Value from your Mapper
- Reducer

  - All values will be grouped by the same key, so here you'll just need to process each input value and calculate the min, max and sum for each column
  - Finally output your result

You might want to look at using Apache Pig which should make this task much easier (untested):

```
grunt> A = LOAD '/path/to/data.txt' USING PigStorage(' ') 
           AS (key, fld1:float, fld2:float, fld3:float);
grunt> GRP = GROUP A BY key;
grunt> B = FOREACH GRP GENERATE $0, MIN(fld1), MAX(fld1), SUM(fld1), 
                                    MIN(fld2), MAX(fld2), SUM(fld2), 
                                    MIN(fld3), MAX(fld3), SUM(fld3);
grunt> STORE B INTO '/path/to/output' USING PigStorage('\t', '-schema');
```